# Django model not saving changes via save_model method

Tags: django, django-admin

I have overridden the admin save_model function to do some extra logic based on custom buttons I have added to the admin site. The save_model function is shown below:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.last_updated = timezone.now()
    send_request = False

    if request.method == 'POST' and "text_gig" in request.POST:
        if not obj.status:
            obj.status = Event.APPROVED

            send_request = True 

            messages.success(request, 'Event has been approved and tweeted!')

        elif _check_tweet(request, form, obj):
            if change:
                obj.tweet = form.cleaned_data.get('tweet')

            send_request = True

            messages.success(request, 'Event has been tweeted!')

        obj.save()
        if send_request:
            send_text.delay(obj.id, phone=False)
```

The instance's "last_updated" should change to the current time, and the "status" field should be set from NULL to the defined constant. However, this is not happening. I know the code flow is proper because I receive the "Event has been approved and tweeted!" message, and because my "send_text" task is firing. Furthermore, I have output from debug logs showing the SQL UPDATE:

```
UPDATE `booking_event` SET `reference` = '046A', `recorded` = '2017-02-26 15:59:29', `customer_id` = 1, `start` = '2017-02-28 17:00:00', `end` = '2017-02-28 20:00:00', `num_bartenders` = 1, `rate` = '20.00', `location` = 'xxx', `attendees` = 100, `description` = 'dsd', `special_requests` = 'dsd', `minimum_training_id` = 2, `contracted` = NULL, `assigned` = NULL, `signed` = NULL, `last_updated` = '2017-02-26 16:16:12', `agreement_id` = NULL, `tweet` = '046A: Tuesday 02/28, 12:00 PM-03:00 PM. 1B. xxx', `last_tweeted` = '2017-02-26 16:14:54', `contract_number` = 0, `status` = 1, `echosign_used` = 0, `booked_as_name` = 'xxx', `booked_as_phone` = 'xxx' WHERE `booking_event`.`id` = 46; args=(u'046A', u'2017-02-26 15:59:29', 1, u'2017-02-28 17:00:00', u'2017-02-28 20:00:00', 1, u'20.00', u'xxx', 100, u'dsd', u'dsd', 2, u'2017-02-26 16:16:12', u'046A: Tuesday 02/28, 12:00 PM-03:00 PM. 1B. xxx', u'2017-02-26 16:14:54', 0, 1, False, u'xxx', u'xxx', 46)
```

Note that 'status' here is set to 1. However, when I browse to the instance's change form, "status" is back to NULL. Which is super confusing since the SQL clearly shows it is executing an UPDATE query with 'status' set as 1.

When I load up the shell and make the change manually it works. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but can't figure this out! Thanks!

---- UPDATE -----

I went closer to the source and enabled transaction logging on the database. A dump of those logs shows a second UPDATE call being made that is reverting my changes!

```
UPDATE `booking_event` SET `reference` = '046A', `recorded` = '2017-02-26 15:59:29', `customer_id` = 1, `start` = '2017-02-28 17:00:00', `end` = '2017-02-28 20:00:00', `num_bartenders` = 1, `rate` = '20.00', `location` = 'xxx', `attendees` = 100, `description` = 'dsd', `special_requests` = 'dsd', `minimum_training_id` = 2, `contracted` = NULL, `assigned` = NULL, `signed` = NULL, `last_updated` = '2017-02-26 16:03:01', `agreement_id` = NULL, `tweet` = 'xxx', `last_tweeted` = '2017-02-26 16:36:48', `contract_number` = 0, `status` = NULL, `echosign_used` = 0, `booked_as_name` = 'xxx', `booked_as_phone` = 'xxx' WHERE `booking_event`.`id` = 46
```

Note how "status" is back to NULL for this query. Any idea what is causing the query to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself :) the "send_text" task that I was dispatching also called the instance's save() method, which introduced a race condition. If the task fetched the instance before the save completed, then the status would become overwritten.

I fixed this by moving all save logic into the admin save_model method.